# Angular Model Driven Forms - Two-way data-binding

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular2-forms

How can model driven forms be used to both initialize a control's value, and bind to an underlying data model?

I've [created a Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/9BxWRfkV5t9CVvn26Rjd/) with a single Model Driven form in Angular 2. There are four input controls: `controlA`, `controlB`, `controlC` and `controlD`:

```
<form novalidate
      [formGroup]="form">

    <input mdInput
           placeholder="A"
           formControlName="controlA">

    <input mdInput
           placeholder="B"
           formControlName="controlB"
           [value]="data.B">

    <input mdInput
           placeholder="C"
           formControlName="controlC"
           (input)="data.C = $event.target.value">

    <input mdInput
           placeholder="D"
           formControlName="controlD"
           [(ngModel)]="data.D">

</form>
```

All input controls belong the same `FormGroup` named `form`, but they each take a different approach to data-binding.

- **controlA** - Only use `FormControlName`
- **controlB** - Use `FormControlName` and grab value directly from underlying mode.
- **controlC** - Use `FormControlName` and update model directly.
- **controlD** - Use `FormControlName` and two-way data binding syntax.

The component defines `createForm()`, called from `ngOnInit()` to create for Model Driven form:

```
export class Tree implements OnInit {

  data = {
    A: 'Data A',
    B: 'Data B',
    C: 'Data C',
    D: 'Data D',
  };

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm() {
    const suffix = ' createForm()';

    this.form = this._fb.group({
            controlA: [{value: this.data.A + suffix, disabled: false}],
            controlB: [{value: this.data.B + suffix, disabled: false}],
            controlC: [{value: this.data.C + suffix, disabled: false}],
            controlD: [{value: this.data.D + suffix, disabled: false}],
    });
  }

}
```

The underlying model being bound to is a simple Java
Script object with four properties, one for each input control:

```
  data = {
    A: 'Data A',
    B: 'Data B',
    C: 'Data C',
    D: 'Data D',
  };
```

The Model Driven form uses the underlying model to initialize each form control, however it adds a suffix `createForm()` to make it obvious when a control is showing data from the underlying model, or from the Form Group.

```
  private createForm() {
    const suffix = ' createForm()';

    this.form = this._fb.group({
            controlA: [{value: this.data.A + suffix, disabled: false}],
            controlB: [{value: this.data.B + suffix, disabled: false}],
            controlC: [{value: this.data.C + suffix, disabled: false}],
            controlD: [{value: this.data.D + suffix, disabled: false}],
    });
```

First thing to note is that only A and C display data from the FormGroup, B and D display data from the binding declared on the host element.

[image]

The next thing to note is that only controls C and D update the model, again, because of the binding declared on the host element.

**I'd like to both initialize an input control using a Form Group, and write that value back to an underlying model.**

The only configuration in my example that achieves this is control C. It is both initialized from the control group and updates the model:

[image]

At this point I think, I must be going wrong. Surely there is an easier and better defined way to initialize using a FormGroup and update an underlying model?

**Solution #1**

Use two-way binding with ngModel:

```
<input mdInput
           placeholder="D"
           formControlName="controlD"
           [(ngModel)]="data.D">
```

The problem here is the the `FormBuilder` does little more than provide a handle to the form control.  There is no need to set a value since the value comes from the model, assuming no `Validators` are required, the `FormBuilder` is **almost** pointless.

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
    controlD: []
});
```

**Solution 2**

Thanks to @harry-ninh for commenting with the idea of subscribing to `FormGroup.valueChanges` and updating the mode from a stream of changes. While this could work for a small number of form controls - if I have a very large form comprised of, potentially hundreds of controls, this because unmanageable.

At the moment I'm leaving towards solution #1 - simply use the `FormGroup` the get a handle on the form within the component, add use `[(ngModel)]` to both set the input value and update the model

Still doesn't feel good though.

Comment: The easiest-to-reason-about way is to subscribe to your `FormGroup.valueChanges` and update the underlying model in the subscription.

Comment: @harry-ninh - Thanks. Added this as a *potential* solution and cited you, but have concerns: While this could work for a small number of form controls - if I have a very large form comprised of, potentially hundreds of controls, this because unmanageable.